# Do we need getter and setter for private variables

Tags: php

Do we really need getter and setter for private variables?
Since they are only used in the object and nowhere else I 
think there is no need.

I looked in some frameworks and I saw that there is a mix.
Sometimes there are getter/setter sometimes not (Symfony2 framework for example).

My opinion is that they only take too much lines of code in my class.

Comment: Uhhhm didn't you just answer your own question?

Comment: If field need access from outside class, then should make getter.

Comment: No, there's no need if you're only gonna access them from within the object. Obviously.

Comment: Yes I mean I only want it to access inside my object

Answer (score 0):

You only need a setter or getter if you want to change or read the value. If you only make a getter for example the value is readonly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs, but even if you are using them just internally, consider the following scenario:

```
class CalendarEvent{

  private $date;

  // with type hinting, you are sure to deal with a DateTime instance  
  public function setDate(DateTime $date){
    $this->date = $date;
  }

  public function getDate(){
    return $this->date;
  }

}
```

Be consistent across all your codebase, in my opinion it would not harm to have getters/setters for each property.

[*Taking up too many lines of code* should be no argument, as long as they are useful.]

Comment: And exactly how useful is it?

Comment: @dan-klasson [you run into an Exception if you fail to meet the criteria](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php), for instance ^^

Comment: Lets say I have a class with two properties. The class only uses the properties internally. And I do not want that other objects can access this properties. If I implement getter/setter for my 2 properties the getter/setter have to be private. Well, I guess it need to be evaluated case to case.

Answer (score 0):

Even if privately (inside the object) if you want to set/change several times the value of the private attribute you could benefit of getter/setter if you have to do manipulation/validation of the value, ie some sanitization, control if empty or something like that... it is just a guideline, not a rule, and it has to be evaluated in every case.